# i want to get the character that a string is made of. for example if i have str=aabbc then the answer is abc

Tags: java, vector

Here is the function i wrote. it take a Stringbuffer text then assign `v[0]=text[0]` , then starts from `text[1] >>>text[n-1]` the comparing. The vector `v` should contain the characters. I don't know where is the problem. Can you help me?

```
   public void setdirectory(StringBuffer text)
   {   
       String temp;
       boolean t;
       v.add(0,String.valueOf(text.charAt(0))); //A[0]=first letter in text.

       for(int i=1;i<text.length();++i)
       {
           temp=String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
           try{

        for(int j=0;j<v.capacity();++j)
           {

               if(!temp.equals(v.elementAt(j)))
               {

                    v.add(i,temp);

               }



                 v.trimToSize();

           }



           //   System.out.println(v.capacity());


       }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)   
       {
           System.out.println("usage error");
       }

       }
       }
```

Comment: Break the `String` down to a `char` array, add all the elements to a `Set` of some kind, get each individual `char` back and reassemble the `String`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 8+, then it might be simpler to use the new Stream API...

```
String str = "aabbc";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
str.chars().distinct().forEach(c -> sb.append((char)c));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Which prints

```
abc
```

Comment: @KickButtowski Yeah, it's dragging me up, kicking a scream ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd write a function to get unique characters, and assuming you need to preserve the insertion order, I'd use a [`LinkedHashSet<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and I'd prefer `StringBuilder` over `StringBuffer`. Something like

```
static String getUniqueCharacters(String text) {
    Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
        set.add(ch);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : set) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative Java 8 solution is:

```
String str = "aabbc";
String str2 = str.chars().distinct().mapToObj(j->""+(char)j).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(str2);
```

Behind the scenes, this is similar to other answers here as `IntStream::distinct` is implemented using a `LinkedHashSet<Integer>`, and `joining` uses a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of where you are adding your value in the vector. Also the number of objects in a vector is size(), not capacity() (look up the API for both; capacity() shows the current number of 'spaces' filled and available to fill before the vector needs to expand, it doesn't show how much of it has actually been filled).

Doh, and the third reason your code would not have worked: you were adding the character every time it found a non-matching one in the vector (over-writing itself each time so you would have only seen the last addition)

```
public void setdirectory(StringBuffer text) {   
   String temp;
   boolean t;
   int addAt = 0;
   v.add(addAt,String.valueOf(text.charAt(0))); //A[0]=first letter in text.

   for(int i=1;i<text.length();++i) {
       temp=String.valueOf(text.charAt(i));
       try {
           boolean found = false
           for(int j=0;j<v.size();++j) {

               if(temp.equals(v.elementAt(j))) {
                   found = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (!found) {
               addAt++;
               v.add(addAt,temp);
           }
       } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
           System.out.println("usage error");
       }
   }
}
```

And although this would fix your code as it stands (which will be an important exercise for a beginner programmer), there are other ways of doing this that you should explore.